# Development in Team: Provider Hosted Apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, certificate, team

My team and I are developing a provider hosted app. Our code source is team foundation server.
Everybody has its own SharePoint Server and all have a common AD.

For the provider hosted app we created a certificate with the `prepares2s.ps1` from Andrew Connell. Every time someone uses the certificate from another team member, the app could be registered by the script but when debugging the get a 401 when executing the clientcontext call.

Whats the problem with the certificate and how can we work together as a team?

Comment: Side question: why does everyone have their own sharepoint box if you're using the new app model? (One of the major benefits of the new app model is that developers don't need to be running VS on the SP box)

Comment: Because we're not only implementing apps. We do farm soultions too. And for that we need our own machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are developing/debugging a provider hosted (high-trust app for SharePoint) in Visual Studio, the remote web application is hosted in IIS Express on the machine where Visual Studio is installed. So the remote web application computer doesn't have an IIS Manager where you can create the certificate. For this reason, you use the IIS on the SharePoint test server to create the certificate

So each of team member should use self-signed certificate of their own development server ([see how to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx)). As long as team members share SAME naming conventions for e.g. certificate name, IssuerID and Client Signing password, you can easily develop/debug apps and work like a team using TFS/version control.
ClientID is something to be taken care by Visual Studio itself, so don't worry about it.

```
<add key="ClientId" value="463e7dff-b7cd-4f48-b846-8c5ce67f5efd" />
<add key="ClientSigningCertificatePath" value="C:\cert\SomeCertficate.pfx" />
<add key="ClientSigningCertificatePassword" value="SomePassword" />
<add key="IssuerId" value="Some-GUID" />
```